# Angular2 ngIf self.context.$implicit.'function name' is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm displaying a path on a google map via angular2-google-maps.
My problem is when I try to add a marker on polylinepoints depending on a certain condition, checked by my method "isDisplayable()"

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <sebm-google-map-polyline *ngFor="let user of followedUsers" [strokeColor]="user.IsSelected ? '#0277BD' : 'grey'">
        <sebm-google-map-polyline-point *ngFor="let userDataEvent of user.UserData.EventsList" [latitude]="userDataEvent.Lat" [longitude]="userDataEvent.Long">
            <sebm-google-map-marker *ngIf="userDataEvent.isDisplayable()" [latitude]="userDataEvent.Lat" [longitude]="userDataEvent.Long" [iconUrl]="user.IsSelected ? 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png' : 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_grey.png' ">
            </sebm-google-map-marker>
        </sebm-google-map-polyline-point>
    </sebm-google-map-polyline>
</sebm-google-map>
```

I iterate over my users to display each user path, and over an event list to get each points of my line.

My UserDataEvent class :

```
import { EventData } from './EventData';

export class UserDataEvent {
    ID: string;
    Lat: number;
    Long: number;
    Date: string;

    ListsEvent: EventData[];

    isDisplayable(): boolean {
        let result: boolean = false;

        for (var eventData of this.ListsEvent)
        {
            if (eventData.TypeEvent == 1 || eventData.TypeEvent == 2 || eventData.TypeEvent == 7 || eventData.TypeEvent == 8) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I got the exception : "self.context.$implicit.isDisplayable is not a function"

I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

little bit late to the party, but it probably didn't work because you didn't assign a value to ListsEvent. Therefore your loop var eventdata of this.ListsEvent breaks your code. Also you could throw overboard and use let instead.

Comment: I don't work for the project's company anymore, but I had resolved this. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @jorghe94 It was 2 years ago, but from what I can remember userDataEvent from "userDataEvent.isDisplayable()" was not a UserDataEvent. That's why it could not find the function